# ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation

Tags: php, apache, nginx

[image]

I use `convert --version` check.

And I follow:

```
$ echo "extension=imagick.so" | sudo tee

/etc/php/mods-available/imagick.ini 
# Symlink it to fpm $ sudo ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/imagick.ini 

/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-imagick.ini

 # Symlink it to cli $ sudo ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/imagick.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini

 # Reload php-fpm sudo service php7.0-fpm reload
```

but ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation.
I am using php 7 and nginx.

Comment: Are there more imagick installations in your machine?

Comment: no. i only install imagick. I try new ImageManager(array('driver' => 'imagick')).

Comment: convert -version is for Imagemagick and not Imagick. You can check if Imagick is installed by viewing your php.ini file as it should be listed.

Comment: hi Bonze. i think imagemagick like imagick.

Comment: I follow https://gist.github.com/nivv/5d9a12af5472b91606e6.